# Connecting to tomcat from LAN:

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I just installed Apache Tomcat 7 on my Windows 7 machine. My question is, how can I connect to this server from another computer in my home. ideally id like to connect with something like 192.168.*.*:8080 but that does not seem to be working now. This is on a private network so my understanding is that ports being block should not be an issue right? I mean if the computer can ping each other.

Thank you.

**Update:** I turned of my windows firewall and I was able to connect from another machine. However, I want to do this while my firewall is on. How would I allow it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the firewall be up on the `Tomcat` installed computer

[How to configure firewalls and Network Address Translation (NAT) for Windows Media Services 9 Series](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827562) -->  refer section --> Enabling access to an encoder outside a firewall

Comment: very possible. i have Microsoft and Security Essentials installed. I can ping other machines on the LAN but not mine. How could i change that?